# Apollo subscription issue - updateQuery not firing

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-apollo

I have a functioning web socket created with Apollo's WebSocketLink interface. I managed to subscribe to an event using `subscribeToMore` and a message is pushed by the server (can see it in the network tab). Unfortunately `updateQuery` function is never triggered. I wonder whether it's the message structure that is incorrect (therefore a wrong server implementation) or is it something wrong in my client code.

For reference I added the message sent from server:

[image]

and here the graphql config for my component:

```
import { graphql } from "react-apollo/index";
import Insights from 'components/insights/Insights';
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import get from 'lodash/get';

const query = gql`
  query CampaignInsights($campaignId: ID) {
    campaigns (id: $campaignId) {
      edges {
        node {
          insights {
            campaignPlanningInsight {
              campaign
              plannedTotals {
                totalOptimizationRules
                totalOfferGroups
                totalOffers
              }
              liveTotals {
                totalOptimizationRules
                totalOfferGroups
                totalOffers
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
`;

const insightsSubscription = gql`
  subscription onInsightsUpdated($campaignId: ID) {
    campaignPlanningInsightUpdated(id: $campaignId) {
      id
      plannedTotals {
        totalOptimizationRules
        totalOfferGroups
        totalOffers
      }
      liveTotals {
        totalOptimizationRules
        totalOfferGroups
        totalOffers
      }
    }
  }
`;

const InsightsWithData = graphql(query, {
  options: (props) => {
    return {
      variables: {
        campaignId: props.match.params.campaignId
      }
    }
  },
  props: ({ data: { campaigns, subscribeToMore }, ownProps: { match } 
}) => {
    return {
      insights: get(campaigns, 
'edges[0].node.insights[0].campaignPlanningInsight', null),
      subscribeToInsightsUpdate: () => {
        return subscribeToMore({
          document: insightsSubscription,
          variables: {
            campaignId: match.params.campaignId
          },
          updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
            debugger; // never gets here
            if (!subscriptionData.data) {
              return prev;
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
})(Insights);

export default withRouter(InsightsWithData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue might be the `id` of the `graphql-ws` websocket protocol.

That `id` needs to match the one sent by the frontend in the `GQL_START` message. Otherwise, the component won't re-render on a new message.

For more details, look into the `subscription-transport-ws` [protocol](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md)